# Lagging JavaScript when opening and closing menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have some lag coming from opening up the menu. I have listed my site so you can view it:

http://www.Skarchmit.tumblr.com

As a side note: links to external scripts and css do not do anything - they are directly in the code with  and similar tags. Some images have not yet been uploaded yet. And appear as question marks.

My current way of making the menu :

Content: 100%, menu: 0px;
Click on it
Content left -250px, menu : 250px

Everything is float.

Im not sure if thats the best way, but its seems laggy on mobile devices especially.

How would i best optimize it for speed?

```
<http://jsfiddle.net/skarchmit/LbgQJ/2/>
```

Comment: Add code please. 
also, try to paste your menu at jsfiddle (or similar) and test it there.

Comment: It does feel Laggy on iPad, but you have to post some code for us to determine the reason of that.

Comment: we really need to see some code to say anything useful. In the mean while, read this excellent post on animation performance: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, it's performing fine on my personal mobile device. However, you can try using the `transform` css property to compare (it has performed better for me in history, especially with hardware acceleration).

Example:

```
.content {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);  
}
.content.open {
  transform: translate3d(-250px, 0, 0);  
}
```

Comment: just as an addition, you would need to write a transition rule like `transition: transform 0.5s. And by assuming 3d transforms, you're missing any ie9 users. In that case you could just fall back to 2d, but in any case, still more performant than animating `left` prop.

Comment: I haven't use it yet. Trying to figure it out :/